# What is the self cherishing attitude?

Tags: mahayana

And to whom does it arise?

As spoken about by Dr. Berzin?

Listen to Seven Point Mind Training by Study Buddhism on #SoundCloud
https://soundcloud.com/studybuddhism/7-point-mind-training

Answer (score 1):

It's described in a couple of pages of *The Complete Foundation: The Systematic Approach to Training the Mind* by HH the Dalai Lama.

I paraphrase:

> - It is the one object of all blame -- the source of all miseries therefore the only object to be blamed for all misfortune.
> - Normally we blame others because we are self-righteous
> - Problems come from the kind of body we assume, which is contaminated and a product of actions -- we possess that body because of attachment to self -- therefore it's attachment to self that gives rise to suffering.
> - "The self-cherishing and self-grasping attitudes abide strongly fortified in the mind, we have never been able to shake the in the least."
> - It leads to wars (globally) and problems within the family.
> - It also leads to arguments between people with one assuming they have more truth than the other.
> - The chronic disease of cherishing myself
>     is the cause of unwanted suffering
>     Perceiving this, may I be inspired
>     To blame, begrudge, and destroy
>     This self-cherishing demon.

When I read a bit of https://www.google.com/search?q=%22self-cherishing+attitude%22 it seems to include both what Theravada calls "conceit" (e.g. "I am better than you") and other vices, e.g. attachments (and I don't know about comfort-seeking too ... and presumably "becoming" and "birth" and so too).

It possibly doesn't include "the view of a real personal identity" which (as in Theravada) might be stated as a separate problem.

"Bodhicitta" is maybe meant to be the antidote, to the "self-cherishing attitude". I've also seen on video his holiness say that he sees himself as "not special" and "just, like everyone else" -- because otherwise he would be/feel imprisoned (in/by his identity).

Combining the last two paragraphs above, I wonder if sunyata rather than Bodhicitta is the antidote to "the view of a real personal identity" -- but sunyata (without Bodhicitta) isn't enough by itself to get rid of the "self-cherishing attitude".

Comment: `What theravada calls conceit? Can conceit walk on earth?` You saw the topic in which Ven Yuttadhammo described "conceit", it's also described here on Wikipedia: [Māna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C4%81na). Among other things it's identified as a major cause of sectarian argument (e.g. "I know better than you do" etc.).

Comment: `Separate problem? Separate from what and what?` I was saying that, although HH describes the "self-cherishing attitude" as the only problem or the root problem, in another text I saw it identified as one of two problems -- with the other problem being "the view of a real personal identity".

Comment: `Are you calling HH dalai lama conceited?` No the opposite -- his saying that "I see myself as being like everyone else" (and not "better than everyone else") seems to be the opposite or absence of conceit.

Comment: `I doubt one could develop proper bodhicitta without doing sunyata` As you might have seen, the Theravada doctrine is that "identity view" is the first to be eradicated (i.e. before "conceit" is). I guess they might be both a little-by-little step-by-step -- and "gradual training" includes generosity (*dana*) early on, that is, before "stream-entry".

Comment: I'm saying Theravada doctrine identifies a fetter called "identity view" which might correspond to what Mahayana doctrine calls "the view of a real personal identity". And Theravada identifies several other fetters, which including "conceit" and others -- and that these may all correspond to or be different aspects of what Lojong calls "self-cherishing attitude".